# Hierarchy of launching activities in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-launcher

I have a confusion with how android starts its launcher activities.

1. If I am declaring a launcher activity in the `manifest` file like this

   ```
   <activity android:name=".Activities.Home">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

and I have an `Application` class which calls an `activity` based on a check like

```
if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Home.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

which one has the precedence ? The `manifest` or the `Application`. What is the flow of events ? **e.g. Application->Manifest (or) Manifest->Application (or) Application overrides Manifest ?**

2. If I am receiving a `notification` in Android, my Application class is called. This makes the activities in the application class to be started, like shown above. Is there a way to detect who calls the Application class  ? **I mean whether the user starts it, or it starts from the `notification` which comes in ?**
3. If there is a way to figure this out. **How do I prevent the activity in the Application class to be called when I receive a notification ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the boolean extras from application and make the diffrence in the call from Application class and User Launch.

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(context,Home.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       intent.putExtra("APP_CALL",True);
       startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your Home activity Just check for APP_CALL if it is called from Application class then bool value will be true else false.

Also you can write in splash activity for checking login .

Comment: Can you explain how it works ? Can you answer all my 3 questions.

Comment: Updated my answer have a look

Comment: I no need to send this to my HomeClass as I am not doing anything there. I need to check in the Application class whether, the application class was called by the user or a incoming notification triggered it ?

Comment: so add intent extras to notification then

Comment: I think you are in some sort of hurry. Never mind. Thanks for your time.

Comment: wont it solve problem bu adding intent extras..just make it clear  why it wont work

Comment: My question is HOW ? Can you say with an example ? I have a notification listener which listens to incoming notification. I dont get where the application class is called from that. If I know that only I cant send the what so ever extras.

Comment: post your notification listener and Intent which triggers notification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336219/app-opens-up-when-i-receive-notification-from-gcm

Comment: Why you want to write Activity launching login in Application .it will always raise several issue like even  broadcast or recreation of service by OS will start your Application class .You should not write those logic here. it is an android's basics application fundamentals

Comment: Can you suggest where can I move it ?

Comment: lets do it from notification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82935/discussion-between-shaik-md-ashiq-and-shakeeb-ayaz).